# on hover image size in mobile view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have profile image thumbnail and on hover larger image get visible which is present in span..
It works perfectly in browser for large screen but showing same size larger image on hover in mobile view..

https://jsfiddle.net/5L88ww69/

HTML :

```
   <a href="#" class="thumbnail2"> 
                          <img src="img/user/04.jpg" width="60" height="60" class="img-thumbnail"/>
                          <span style="top:60px; left: 60px; width: 400px;height: 450px;"><img src="img/user/04.jpg" class="img-thumbnail"/><br /></span>
                        </a>
```

CSS:

```
  .thumbnail2  {
  position: relative;
   float: left;
   z-index: 50;
  }

 .thumbnail2:hover span {
  visibility: hidden;
 }

.thumbnail2 span { 
  position: absolute;
  padding: 5px;
  visibility: hidden;
 text-decoration: none;
 }

.thumbnail2 span img { 
 border-width: 0px; 
 }


.thumbnail2:hover span { 
  visibility: visible; 
  width: 800px;
  height: 800px;
  top: 60px; 
  left: 60px;
 }
```

how to show larger image in mobile view which perfectly fits in mobile view?

Comment: Have you tried changing width and height into percent value?

Comment: no.. please suggest me how it should be

Comment: you can use bootstrap and class name img-responsive

Comment: no its not working @claudios

Comment: I have used but img-responsive showing original size of image in mobile view... @Ozgur Ersil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `media query`

```
 @media all and (max-width: 600px){
   .thumbnail2 span {
    left: 0!important;
    width: 100%!important;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.thumbnail2 span img {
    width: 100%!important;
}
 }
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5L88ww69/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set width and height in percent value like this.

```
.thumbnail2:hover span { 
  visibility: visible; 
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  top: 60px; 
  left: 60px;
 }
```